# Windows won't see new drives

Tags: windows

I've had this happen to me multiple times over the years, both XP and Win 7 yet I can't find any mention of it on the web:

Something gets messed up in Windows and it gets picky about seeing mass storage devices.  A drive that is known will continue to work but an unknown drive, even if it's just a known one on a different USB or SATA port will not be seen.  I can't find any indication of it in disk manager or device manager.

It's been long enough since it happened that I can't remember if it needs a full reinstall or just a repair install to fix but neither is fun.

This is **NOT** a hardware failure of any kind.

This time it's my Kindle that won't be recognized.  Plugging it into another machine worked fine, I shared it and copied over the files I wanted to copy.

This time I have one hint--I have 5 unknown devices in Devices and Printers and a label printer has died and been replaced with another one with the same name + Copy 1.  Zapping them can make the original come back but soon it gets replaced with the Copy 1 again.

Any solutions beyond the hard one?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating all your drivers first.  I suggest slimdrivers.com

Comment: What driver failure could cause it to suddenly stop working??

Comment: @LorenPechtel  Since, you give me no details (chipset, sata controller,motherboard or etc), I have to make educated guesses.  Some USB,SATA,AHCI, and others have bugs in the drivers that require new versions and/or firmware updates.  I just got on 5/14 an update to my BIOS that says improves compatibility with USB devices.  Your USB ports could be starting to break also.

Comment: I said this wasn't a hardware issue because I knew people would start out assuming it's a hardware failure.  I've seen this exact same failure on completely different hardware and after reinstalling the old hardware will work fine.  This is software, not hardware!

Comment: I have seen tons of issues caused by out-of-date drivers.  Having no knowledge of your system you could be using all drivers from 2003 and that would make your system quirky and slow.

Comment: 2003 drivers on Win 7???  Everything was current as of 6 months ago.

Comment: To verify your theory, I would suggest the following test.  Find a 40gb or old hard drive laying around.  Turning the system off, unplug your existing hard drive and plug the spare in load windows and see if it is all better or not.  Then tweaking.com has a registry compressor which would repair damage structural damage to if the registry if it exists.  Also I would run tweaking.com "windows repair" tool, all the repair options to verify all is the way it is supposed to be.